# Union and Intersection of data

Tags: mysql, algorithm, intersection

I have three tables:

user

```
id | name
------------------
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
3  | Baz
```

group_type

```
id | name
------------------
1  | Group 1
2  | Group 2
3  | Group 3
4  | Group 4
5  | Group 5
```

user_group

```
id | user_id | group_type_id | [..]
------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1             | [..]
2  | 1       | 3             | [..]
3  | 2       | 1             | [..]
4  | 1       | 5             | [..]
5  | 2       | 3             | [..]
6  | 3       | 3             | [..]
```

Well, currently, I can find all users from a specified list of groups with union, which is like a "or" clause:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   user u,
       user_group ug
WHERE  ug.user_id = u.id
       AND ug.group_type_id IN( 1, 3, 5 )
```

Resulting:

```
id | name
------------------
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
3  | Baz
```

Now, I need to intersect the gorup, find all users which have groups of type 1 AND 3, resulting:

```
id | name
------------------
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
```

I have tried some queries, but don't imagine a way of doing this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN user_group g 
  ON u.id = g.user_id 
WHERE ug.group_type_id IN (1,3) 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name 
HAVING count(distinct ug.group_type_id) = 2
```

Not as clean as the normal case, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: +1 @schizodactyl - beat me by about 10 seconds :) If I could, I'd give another +1 for the ANSI join.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use INTERSECT query. The syntax for the SQL INTERSECT query is:

```
select field1, field2, ... field_n
from tabl,tab2...
INTERSECT
select field1, field2, ... field_n
from tablel,table2...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my syntax is perfect, but I'd reccomend self-joining user_group onto itself using user_id and forcing one of the selected entries (ug1 and ug2) to have ug1.group_type_id=1 and the other ug2.group_type_id=3. This gives you all user_id's with 1 AND 3 as their group_type_id. Now that you have that, you can do another join onto your user table, giving you all of the results that you were looking for.

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u 
JOIN (SELECT ug1.user_id 
    FROM user_group ug1 JOIN user_group ug2 
    ON ug1.user_id=ug2.user_id
    WHERE ug1.group_type_id=1 and ug2.group_type_id=3) ug
ON u.id=ug.user_id
```